What is this error related to report generation?
I'm working on project that generates various reports one of them is trend chart report but I'm getting this error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unrecognized document structure: {"color":"#0000","alignment":"right","fontSize":13,"margin":[0,35,10,0]}
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31)
    at zone.js:1285:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at core.mjs:23896:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23896:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24197:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:588:35);

The error is related to this code
if (tempFilter.reportTypeName == 'Trend_Chart_Report') {
            this.downloadtrendReport = true;
            tempFilter.generateExcel = false;
            tempFilter.objectProperties.forEach((obj) => {
              obj._chileNodes = null;
            });
            this.subscription.add(this.apiService.trendSeriesChart(tempFilter).subscribe(res => {
              //pass res to both method and trendchartData coz we have used res in pdfmake code to create color table
              this.trendchartData = res;
              this.convertLevelAndSeriesNameDataToKeyAsASeriesName(res);
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.downloadchart();
              }, 1000);
              this.value = 100;
              this.stopSignal.next('');
              this.showspinner = false;
              this.sharedService.setLoading(false);
              //this.getDownloadable();
              this.sharedService.showSucessMessage(res.msg);
              this.isReportGenerated = true;
              this.clearPdf = true;
            },
              error => {
                this.stopSignal.next('');
                this.showspinner = false;
                this.sharedService.setLoading(false);
                this.sharedService.showErrorMessage("Something is wrong, Report is not generated.");
              }
            )
            )
          }


How do I resolve it.
I tried various debugging attempts but couldn't understand anything, This functionality is expected to generate and download trend chart report.

What is tempFilter?
